# Запретить переход фокуса с элемента в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть панель со слушателями кнопок, на ней рисуются графики функций. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на стрелки клавиатуры, фокус оставался на этой панели и не переходил к другим элементам.

Comment: Возможно поможет метод `some_node.setFocusTraversable(false)`, но это не точно.

Comment: Не поможет. он не позволяет перевести фокус на данный элемент, а не убрать с него. Есть хреновое решение, при котором я могу сделать это со всеми элементами кроме панели и добавить к каждому элементу слушатель, но это ужасно неудобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, достаточно просто "подавить" события на нажатия этих кнопок:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFX990084 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("990084");

        TextField tf1 = new TextField();
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Start");

        // на примере текстового поля
        // перехватываем нажатия нужных клавиш
        tf1.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB
                        || event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP
                        || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN
                        || event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT
                        || event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
                    event.consume();
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(16);
        root.getChildren().add(tf1);
        root.getChildren().add(tf2);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```